# The "close" icon on the "question has been deleted" banner has turned into a pacman ghost

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, icons

Oops, the post I was writing an answer on has been deleted...

[image: This question has been deleted – no more answers will be accepted.]

Wait... what is *that*?

[image: oh noes pacman]

It's the end of days! D:

Seriously, though, it looks like there's something wrong with the sprite that's supposed to be there. I don't know what. I'm running Chrome 41.0.2272.104 on Mac OS X 10.10.2, for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was just a sprite problem (got it?). It's now fixed.