# Merge or synonymize the [icon] and [icons] tags on MSE

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, retag-request, synonym-request

I wrote [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252116/188673), and in doing so, I found out that we have two tags, [icon](/questions/tagged/icon) and [icons](/questions/tagged/icons). These are identical. Can someone merge them or set up a tag synonym for them?

There aren't many questions here, so I'd retag them manually, but I don't have the rep to edit everything without approval, so I didn't want to create a huge number of suggested edits.

Comment: With so few questions and no tag wiki, I assume both may end up burninated.

Comment: What about putting them into [tag:logo]?

Comment: Looks like both tags have stuck around for over 7 years now.